# Update multiple distinct columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to update multiple rows at once, but only distinct rows.

SQL code:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9c6bdd/4

As you can see from the select statement in the fiddle - I want to update rows using where and distinct conditions.

Update should change IDOrder value, for TOP 1 (LIMIT 1) row, where GroupP is the same

Example:

```
(IDPobocka, IDCinnost, Termin, IDOrder)
```

Input:

```
(1, 10,'2019-05-02 11:00:00', NULL),
(1, 10,'2019-05-02 11:00:00', NULL),
(1, 10,'2019-05-02 11:00:00', NULL),
(1, 11,'2019-05-02 11:00:00', NULL),
(1, 11,'2019-05-02 11:00:00', NULL),
(1, 11,'2019-05-02 11:00:00', NULL),
(1, 11,'2019-05-02 11:00:00', NULL),
```

Output:

```
(1, 10,'2019-05-02 11:00:00', 1234),
(1, 10,'2019-05-02 11:00:00', NULL),
(1, 10,'2019-05-02 11:00:00', NULL)
(1, 11,'2019-05-02 11:00:00', 1234),
(1, 11,'2019-05-02 11:00:00', NULL),
(1, 11,'2019-05-02 11:00:00', NULL),
(1, 11,'2019-05-02 11:00:00', NULL),
```

Comment: Your rows are exactly identical.  I don't think there is a way to do what you want without adding another column to the table.  Why not just delete the duplicates, so you have only one row per combination?

Comment: You need to add a primary key... or any type of key to identify rows uniquely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix your data model so you can distinguish the rows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Test (
    TestId int auto_increment primary key,
    IDPobocka int,
    IDCinnost int,
    Termin datetime,
    IDOrder int
);
```

Then you can simply do:

```
update t join
       (select min(testid) as min_testid
        from test t
        group by IDPobocka, IDCinnost, Termin
       ) tt
       on t.testid = tt.min_testid
    set IDOrder = 1234;
```

Comment: Thanks, but...
Is it possible to change values inside two different rows at the same upload as you can see in Output?

The idea is:
I want to update IDOrder value to all TOP 1 rows for one GroupP records without using some procedure, only with UPDATE statement.
So each TOP1 row for different IDCinnost and same IDPobocka, GroupP will have updated IDOrder value.

Is it possible?

Comment: Solved it, thank you for showing me the way.

Solution without WHERE conditions:

UPDATE WC_Kalendar_Terminu t1
INNER JOIN(
    SELECT IDCinnostNaPobocce, MIN(ID) AS min_id
    FROM WC_Kalendar_Terminu
    INNER JOIN  WC_CINNOST_NA_POBOCCE ON IDCinnostNaPobocce = WC_CINNOST_NA_POBOCCE.ID_W_CINNOST_NA_POBOCCE
    GROUP BY IDCinnostNaPobocce
) t2
    ON t1.IDCinnostNaPobocce = t2.IDCinnostNaPobocce AND
       t1.id         = t2.min_id
    INNER JOIN  WC_CINNOST_NA_POBOCCE ON t1.IDCinnostNaPobocce = WC_CINNOST_NA_POBOCCE.ID_W_CINNOST_NA_POBOCCE
SET t1.IDObjednavka = 1234

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to delete the first of each batch of identical records.

Whilst the permanent solution is to alter the database structure to allow for uniqueness of rows (1st normal form). This is a way of faking that until you get there.

This approach takes the top example of each idcinnost, pushes that in to a separate table. updates those records, finds the top example in the first table, uses a third table to reference that, remove the original row from the original table, then remove that row from the first temp table, then remove that from the 2nd temp table.

It's clunky but the over all effect works and provides the output you are looking for.

```
declare @t table
(
    IDPobocka int, 
    IDCinnost int, 
    Termin datetime, 
    IDOrder int
);

declare @r table
(
 id int
);

insert @t (IDPobocka, IDCinnost, Termin, IDOrder)
values
(1, 10,'2019-05-02 11:00:00', NULL),
(1, 10,'2019-05-02 11:00:00', NULL),
(1, 10,'2019-05-02 11:00:00', NULL),
(1, 11,'2019-05-02 11:00:00', NULL),
(1, 11,'2019-05-02 11:00:00', NULL),
(1, 11,'2019-05-02 11:00:00', NULL),
(1, 11,'2019-05-02 11:00:00', NULL);


select * into #temp from 
(select row_number()over(partition by idcinnost order by idpobocka) rowno, idpobocka, idcinnost, termin, idorder
 from @t) tx where rowno=1;

 update #temp set idorder=1234;

 while exists (select 1 from #temp)
    begin

        delete top (1) t 
        output deleted.IDCinnost into @r
        from @t t inner join #temp te on t.IDCinnost=te.IDCinnost;

        insert @t (IDPobocka, IDCinnost, Termin, IDOrder)
            select IDPobocka, IDCinnost, Termin, IDOrder from #temp t1 inner join @r r1 on t1.IDCinnost=r1.id;

        delete t2 from #temp t2 inner join @r r2 on t2.IDCinnost=r2.id;

        delete from @r;

    end

    drop table #temp;

    select * from @t;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would delette the duplicates, so you have one try for each combination.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not possible.
These rows are being automatically generated for a reason :(